# Spring Cross Origin Resource Sharing : Preflight response is not successful

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, cors, fetch

I have seen a ton of other questions on StackOverflow on this topic, but no solution fixed my problem.

I have a rest API developed with SpringBoot on port `8000` on `localhost`. I'm trying to make a request to an endpoint from the browser's `fetch` API. I have also enabled CORS with the following bean:

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/api/**")
                    .allowedOrigins("*")
                    .allowedHeaders("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
                    .allowCredentials(true)
                    .allowedHeaders("*");
            }
        };
    }
```

Here's my security configuration:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Component
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired private UserService userService;

    public SecurityConfiguration() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/register", "/h2-console/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
        .and().httpBasic();

        http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
        .userDetailsService(userService)
        .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Instead of all this setup, I still get the following error:

```
Preflight response is not successful
Fetch API cannot load http://localhost:8000/api/register/ due to access control checks.
Failed to load resource: Preflight response is not successful
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-cors-preflight

When using spring security, all requests without a valid auth token are blocked unless mentioned explicitly. The browser is sending a request with `options` method. That request will be blocked as per my configuration. So, to exclude `cors` from security, we need to enable it.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .cors().and()
    ...//
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your `SecurityConfiguration`:

```
@Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("x-auth-token", "xsrf-token"));
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But, it's still giving the same response

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().configurationSource(request -> {
                CorsConfiguration cors = new CorsConfiguration();
                cors.setAllowedOrigins(
                        Lists.newArrayList("*"));
                cors.setAllowedMethods(Lists.newArrayList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
                cors.setAllowedHeaders(Lists.newArrayList("*"));
                return cors;
            })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've tried a lot of configurations recently which I found on the Internet :)
I have a slightly different case, I use Kotlin with Spring Boot and WebFlux, but I think in general it should works with Java too.

I found that you must specify cors configuration in SecurityWebFilterChain. Other configurations (including official Spring Security Documentation) don't work.

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
class WebSecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    fun configure(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain? {
        val config = CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues()

        config.maxAge = 8000L
        config.allowCredentials = true
        config.allowedOrigins = listOf("http://localhost:4200")
        config.allowedHeaders = listOf("*")
        config.allowedMethods =
            listOf(HttpMethod.OPTIONS.name, HttpMethod.GET.name, HttpMethod.DELETE.name, HttpMethod.PUT.name)
        config.exposedHeaders = listOf(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN, HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS)

        val source = UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource().apply {
            registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config)
        }

        http
            .cors {
                it.configurationSource(source)
            }
            .authorizeExchange {
                it.pathMatchers("/auth").permitAll()
                it.anyExchange().authenticated()
            }
            .oauth2ResourceServer {
                it.jwt()
            }

        return http.build()
    }
}
```